# CSS issue in Text Editor table layout in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Any changes I make to the css file: `ui.css` dont make any affect in IE7 (IE9 in compatibility mode).

If you go to: [website](http://dev.web2works.co.uk/jacket_cms/tiny_mce) you will see that this loads perfectly in Firefox but the select and the small gaps appear different in IE.

[image]

IE6
[image: IE6]

Comment: Not that it is an answer to you but quit using IE7. IE7 is very old. Also i have seen that the IE7 compatibility mode in IE9 renders differently comparing to the real IE7 and the compatibility mode in IE8. Do not rely on the compatibility modes.

Comment: @casperOne - How on earth can this get any more obvious what is wrong and the question is asking? Can you spot the difference between the images?

Comment: @JohnMagnolia No HTML, no CSS, no indication of *which* text editor (there are a gazillion WYSIWIG text editors out there).  Links to external sites that have this information (especially in the case of HTML/CSS) are pretty much invalid, as once the problem is fixed, all context around this question and answer go away (since the assumption is, you'll fix it there).  You should note also *which* changes you are making, because no one knows exactly what kind of changes you are making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things supported by Firefox or chrome are **not** available in IE(even newer versions)
so you cant rely on it.

maybe you can just show a message prompting the user to get one of those browsers

Answer (score -1):

Try using a conditional stylesheet so you can target ie7 directly or another solution could be installing ie7 on another machine because sometimes ie tester can be buggy(past experience). Last suggestion is to try [browsershots](http://browsershots.org) to test ie7(another method).